# Minikube exposing all services and ports

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using Helm with multiple charts, I have it up and running on the K8s cluster, but for local test, we want to use Minikube with a docker driver, and now I have an issue with accessing the application inside the Minikube network, how can I expose everything to the host? is it even possible?

I can expose the main app with port-forwarding but then all the redirections are not working.

this is all the services.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/#known-issues)  for minikube as it is only limited to Linux. Using minikube service with a tunnel the network is limited if using the Docker driver on Darwin, Windows, or WSL, and the Node IP is not reachable directly. Running a minikube on Linux with the Docker driver will result in no tunnel being created. Follow this [tunneling](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#:%7E:text=minikube%20tunnel%20runs%20as%20a,on%20the%20host%20operating%20system) into Minikube for accessing the application inside the Minikube network. The tunnel command exposes the external IP directly to any program running on the host operating system.

Refer to this [medium blog](https://medium.com/sharmio/how-to-share-a-locally-running-application-in-minikube-with-others-using-kubernetes-services-and-52ab543f6a8c#:%7E:text=The%20Minikube%20tunnel%20command%20creates,connection%20to%20the%20Minikube%20node) by Mohit Sharma for more information.

Comment: the minikube tunnel is not working as I wanted, and the blog you shared is not really explaining anything except running command tunnel